# Generally flatten returned lists in pyparsing

Tags: python, grammar, text-parsing, pyparsing

This one is a bit lengthly to explain, so bear wit me: With  [`pyparsing`](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) I have to analyse many text parts like:

```
first multi segment part 123 45 67890 third multi segment part

------------^----------- -----^------ ------------^-----------
  Part A: alpha words    B: num words   Part C: alpha words
```

I tried to use `pp.OneOrMore` for each part:

```
a = pp.OneOrMore(pp.Word(pp.alphas)).setName("PART_A")('A')
b = pp.OneOrMore(pp.Word(pp.nums)).setName("PART_B")('B')
c = pp.OneOrMore(pp.Word(pp.alphas)).setName("PART_C")('C')
expr = a + b + c
```

When I run this over the string `"first multi segment part 123 45 67890 third multi segment part"` I get

```
- A: ['first', 'multi', 'segment', 'part']
- B: ['123', '45', '67890']
- C: ['third', 'multi', 'segment', 'part']
```

However I want **all** results flattened like:

```
- A: 'first multi segment part'
- B: '123 45 67890'
- C: 'third multi segment part'
```

For this I can use the `setParseAction` function. becasue I will have a lot of constructs using this feature I extended the `OneOrMore` class likes this:

```
class OneOrMoreJoined(pp.OneOrMore):
    """OneOrMore with results joined to one string"""
    def __init__( self, expr, stopOn=None, joinString=' '):
        super(OneOrMoreJoined,self).__init__(expr, stopOn=stopOn)
        self.setParseAction(joinString.join)
```

With this class I get the desired result. :-)

However what can I do if I want a Sequence `d1 + d2` to be joined?:

```
d1 = pp.Word(pp.nums).setName("PART_D1")
d2 = pp.Word(pp.alphas).setName("PART_D2")
expr = (d1 + d2)('D')
```

Of course I an create a new class `AndJoined` and use `AndJoined(d1,d2)`, but then I loose the nice notation `d1 + d2`.

Is there a general way to flatten results? **I could of course flatten the ParseResult manually *outside* after I retrieve the dict**, but I suspect there is an easy way to express this *inside* `pyparsing`...

Comment: If there are multiple spaces between words, do you want the result to have just one space, or the same spaces as in the original string?

Comment: All white-space should be shrunk to single spaces (like the `OneOrMoreJoined` class is suppose to do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest would be to write a small helper like this:

```
joiner = lambda expr: expr.addParseAction(' '.join)
```

Then insert `joiner` in your grammar wherever:

```
a_b_c = joiner(a + b + c | d + Optional(e))
```

Just make sure that the tokens passed to `joiner` are just single level tokens. If they are nested, then you might need a flattener routine, but this is easily added by writing `joiner` as:

```
joiner = lambda expr: expr.addParseAction(flatten, ' '.join)
```

Comment: I like this approach - it keeps the grammar clean! But where is the function `flatten` defined?

Comment: This is left as an exercise for the student.

Comment: Ok, just wanted to check whether there is a (recursive) `flatten` somewhere predefined...

Comment: This works:

    `def flatten (x):
        if isinstance(x, six.string_types):
            return x
        elif not isinstance(x, collections.Iterable):
            return ""
        else:
            flattened_list = [ flatten_to_string(e) for e in x ]
            return " ".join(( f for f in flattened_list if f != ''))

    joiner = lambda expr: expr.addParseAction(flatten)` (Sorry, SE doesn't allow indented code blocks in comments.)

Comment: 'flatten_and_join' might be a better name for this, since it performs both tasks. Also, if not iterable, maybe return `str(x)`, since you might have a non-string non-iterable value in your results (like an int).